# How can I import login credentials from other browsers or keychain or file?

Tags: login

I have passwords stored in keychain and a browser (brave browser) and an exported version as a CSV file. How can I import it to Tor browser login password system?

Thank you

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-o -> Import and Backup -> Import Data from Another Browser Doesn't work. I checked for myself. You might also want to do the same. Tor browser gives the error "No programs that contain bookmarks [...] could be found."

Answer (score 0):

You can import bookmarks but importing any other settings is disabled in Tor Browser.

Check for yourself. It's the same function as in Firefox.

CTRL-SHIFT-o -> Import and Backup -> Import Data from Another Browser

Answer (score 0):

You Must Go Through /about:config/  Type That in A New Browser Window.
Once You Get There, It Will Give You All Kinds of Warnings.  Accept Them.  Once You Reach Destination Site, in Top 'URL'
Type /signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled/
This Will Give You One Choice in Lower Window.  It Will Say /false/  on Right, There is two arrows going Opposite Direction, Enclosed in box.  Tap That.
Make True.

Couple Things:

1. Don't Use the Forward Slash I Have in my Post.  I Just Use That, to Prevent Code Engaging
2. Even Once You establish Import File Rights, TOR Won't Install Them.  You'll Get an Error, That None Were Uploaded.

That's Where I Am.

Answer (score 0):

The safe and correct way to do so is to use KeePassXC secure password manager and a corresponding integration add-on for a browser(s)... Just check it out - and you will see the full and secure answer for your question